# Is it known whether 2-mixing continuous systems on a compact metric space are necessarily "pseudo-3-mixing"?

Tags: ergodic-theory

> Is it known whether, for every mixing measure-preserving dynamical system $(X,\mathcal{B}(X),\mu,T)$ with $X$ a compact metrisable space and $T$ a continuous map, we have that for all $A,B,C \in \mathcal{B}(X)$,
> $$ \mu(A \cap T^{-k}(B) \cap T^{-(k+l)}(C)) - \mu(A \cap T^{-k}(B) \cap T^{-(k+l+1)}(C)) \to 0 \quad \text{as } (k,l) \to (\infty,\infty) ? $$
>
> [Well, I guess it can't be the case that the answer is known to be *no*, as that would then solve Rokhlin's multiple mixing problem. But perhaps it's known (or not too hard to show) that the answer is *yes*?]

---

I ask because:

- if we were to have a counterexamplary $(X,\mathcal{B}(X),\mu,T)$, then (unless I am mistaken) it is not hard to show that one can find $A,B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ with $\mu(A),\mu(B)>0$, sequences $k_n,l_n \to \infty$, and a **non**-$T$-invariant probability measure $\nu$ on $X$, such that for all $C \in \mathcal{B}(X)$,
  $$ \mu(A \cap T^{-k_n}(B) \cap T^{-(k_n+l_n)}(C)) \to \mu(A)\mu(B)\nu(C) \quad \text{as } n \to \infty; $$
- but (again, unless I am mistaken) it is not hard to show that in general, for any mixing measure-preserving dynamical system $(X,\mathcal{X},\mu,T)$, for any $A,B,C \in \mathcal{X}$ with $\mu(A)=\mu(B^c)$,
  $$ \sup_{k \geq 0} \Big( \mu(A \cap T^{-k}(B) \cap T^{-(k+l)}(C)) - \mu(A^c \cap T^{-k}(B^c) \cap T^{-(k+l)}(C)) \Big) \to 0 \quad \text{as } l \to \infty; $$

and so, if in the first bullet point we can take $A,B$ with $\mu(A)=\mu(B^c)$, then writing
\begin{align*}
\mu_k &:= \mu(\,\cdot\,|A \cap T^{-k}(B)) \\
\tilde{\mu}_k &:= \mu(\,\cdot\,|A^c \cap T^{-k}(B^c)),
\end{align*}
we have that for all sufficiently large $n$,

- on the one hand, $\,\mu_{k_n} \!\approx \mu(\,\cdot\,|A)\,$ and $\,\tilde{\mu}_{k_n} \!\approx \mu(\,\cdot\,|A^c)$;
- and yet on the other hand, the trajectories of $\mu_{k_n}$ and $\tilde{\mu}_{k_n}$ under pushforwards of $T$ approximately meet at the same non-invariant measure $\nu$ before approaching $\mu$.

This kind of behaviour feels like quite an awkward behaviour to try and construct for an autonomous dynamical system (in contrast to a non-autonomous system where you're allowed to change the map at each step so as to "brute-force" whatever qualitative behaviour you like).

Comment: I've now asked this on MathOverflow at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452181/